# Print subreport from form (Access 2016)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a Parent Form with a Tab Control, each Tab holding one Report. I am trying to put a command button on my main form that will print the Report on the Active Tab. I am strongly trying to avoid putting a "Print" button on EVERY report.
So far I have done the following:

1.I am using this line of code to open selected report in print preview:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport Right(Me!Rpt0.SourceObject, Len(Me!Rpt0.SourceObject) - 7), acViewPreview
```

It looks so complicated because when you have a report as a subform the source object property is Report.MyReport so I had to eliminate the "Report." part.

So far so good.

2.I have also named all the controls holding the reports according to the index of the tab that holds them. So, Report on page 1 is Rpt0, on page 2 is Rpt1 and so on.

3. I am trying to replace the "Rpt0" part on that line of code with an expression looking like this:

   ```
   myexp= "Rpt" & Me!TabCtl1.TabIndex
   ```

   So the above code becomes:

   ```
   DoCmd.OpenReport Right(Me!myexp.SourceObject, Len(Me!myexp.SourceObject) - 7), acViewPreview
   ```

   and the active report is chosen each time.

My problem is with the Dim As and Set.. I am not familiar with them and it seems that whatever combination I try I get an "Object required" error, or or run-time error '2465': can't find field "myexp".

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport Right(Me(myexp).SourceObject, Len(Me(myexp).SourceObject) - 7), acViewPreview
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gustav!! This was tremendously easy..! In case others have the same problem the final code is this: `Private Sub Print_Report_Click()
Dim sbfname As String
sbfname = "Rpt" & Me.TabCtl1
DoCmd.OpenReport Right(Me(sbfname).SourceObject, Len(Me(sbfname).SourceObject) - 7), acViewPreview
End Sub`(If anyone knows how to add spaces here, please do). I also replaced `Me!tabctl1.TabIndex` with `Me.Tabctl1` cause the first one always gave me the first page and not the "visible" one.

Comment: Great! You could append the final code to your question to make it more readable.